# Join logic from two separate tables in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

We returned a list of `cardID`'s after a query and those `cardID`'s belong to two tables `Student` and `Personnel`. So how can I join those `cardID`'s with `Student` and `Personnel` so I can return a table that shows name of `Student` and `Personnel` according to `cardID`'s?

**Personnel** table:

```
PERSONNELID NUMBER(9,0) 
PERSONNELNAME   VARCHAR2(20)    
PERSONNELSURNAME    VARCHAR2(20)    
PERSONNELJOB    VARCHAR2(40)    
PERSONNELCARDID NUMBER(4,0)
```

**Student** table:

```
STUDENTID   NUMBER(9,0) 
STUDENTNAME VARCHAR2(20)    
STUDENTSURNAME  VARCHAR2(20)    
STUDENTDEPT VARCHAR2(40)    
STUDENTFACULTY  VARCHAR2(20)    
STUDENTCARDID   NUMBER(4,0)
```

**CardID** table

```
   CARDID   NUMBER(4,0) 
   USERTYPE VARCHAR2(20)    
   CHARGE   NUMBER(3,2) 
   CREDIT   NUMBER(4,2)
```

**PaymentDevice** table:

```
    ORDERNO NUMBER  
    PAYDEVIP    NUMBER(8,0) 
    PAYDEVDATE  DATE    No  
    PAYDEVTIME  VARCHAR2(8) 
    CHARGEDCARDID   NUMBER(9,0) 
    MEALTYPE       VARCHAR2(10)
```

I tried to return first 10 person's name and surname that eat at cafeteria on 27/12/2012

```
SELECT C.CARDID
FROM CARD C, PAYMENTDEVICE P
WHERE P.ORDERNO
BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(ORDERNO)
FROM PAYMENTDEVICE
WHERE PAYDEVDATE='27/12/2012') AND (SELECT MIN(ORDERNO)
FROM PAYMENTDEVICE
WHERE PAYDEVDATE='27/12/2012')+10    AND C.CARDID=P.CHARGEDCARDID;
```

Our `orderNo` isn't reset everyday but keeps increasing so we found the min `orderNo` that day and add 10 to this value to find first 10 person who eat on that day between those order numbers.

So what return from this query:

```
  CARDID
  1005
  1000
  1002
  1003
  1009
  2000
  2001
  1007
  2002
  1004
  1006
```

and those some of those cardId (start with 1) are `studentCardId` and some of them (starts with 2) are `PersonnelCardId`. So how can I match and write names accordingly?

Comment: ... You probably ought to have a single `Individual` table, with `id`, `name`, `surname`, and `cardId` in it.  Then modify your existing tables into `Personnel` with `individualId`, `job` and `Student` with `individualId`, `dept`, `faculty`.  Much cleaner.  I mean, what happens if a student also is 'personnel' - do they get a second card?  Would you be expecting them to show up twice in your listing?  Which would be the 'preferred' duplicate?

Comment: can't we find names from different tables according to their cardIds?

Comment: Perhaps you could include sample starting data, and your desired results?

Comment: I edited my question. Can you look at it now, please?

Comment: Yeah, the information you've added helps.  There's still issues with your schema design though - I'd still be wanting an `Individual` table.  Other notes - your date/time columns in `PaymentDevice` (which isn't what the table actually holds) should be a single timestamp-type column.  Even if `orderNo` is monotonically increasing, I'd prefer working with those columns for 'first' sales.  I'm assuming that `Card.userType` refers to personnel/student, and is the actual text; if so, that's dangerous de-normalization, and should be avoided.  The digits used in `Card` seem way too low, all columns.

Comment: "USERTYPE" IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','CITYHALLWORKER','REGULARSTUDENT','INTERNATIONAL','DISABLED','SCHOLAR') Thanks but we have to show this project tomorrow So last time changes would be messy for us. Thank you for the advices, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Personel p INNER JOIN Student s 
ON p.PersonnelCardId = s.StudentCardId 
INNER JOIN ReturnedQuery rq
ON rq.CardId = p.PersonnelCardId
```

updated:

```
    SELECT p.PersonnelName, rq.CardId
    FROM Personel p INNER JOIN ReturnedQuery rq
    ON rq.CardId = p.PersonnelCardId 

    UNION

    SELECT s.StudentName, rq.Cardid
    FROM Student s INNER JOIN ReturnedQuery rq 
    ON s.StudentCardId = rq.Cardid
```

Comment: why do you compare p.PersonnelCardId = s.StudentCardId? They are different.

Comment: But cardId order is broken in that case, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your original query is actually pretty fragile.  I'd rewrite it like so (and added the needed joins):

```
WITH First_Daily_Purchase as (SELECT chargedCardId,
                                     MIN(payDevTime) as payDevTime, 
                                     MIN(orderNo) as orderNo
                              FROM PaymentDevice
                              WHERE payDevDate >= 
                                              TO_DATE('2012-12-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                    AND payDevDate <
                                              TO_DATE('2012-12-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                              GROUP BY chargedCardId),
     First_10_Daily_Purchasers as (SELECT chargedCardId
                                   FROM (SELECT chargedCardId, 
                                                RANK() OVER(ORDER BY payDevTime,
                                                                 orderNo) as rank
                                         FROM First_Daily_Purchase) a
                                   WHERE a.rank < 11)
SELECT a.chargedCardId, b.personnelName, b.personnelSurname
FROM First_10_Daily_Purchasers a
JOIN Personnel b
ON b.personnelCardId = a.chargedCardId
UNION ALL
SELECT a.chargedCardId, b.studentName, b.studentSurname
FROM First_10_Daily_Purchasers a
JOIN Student b
ON b.studentCardId = a.chargedCardId
```

(Have a [working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/418c9/14) - generally bullet-proofing this took me a while.)
This should get you the first 10 people who made a purchase (not the first *11* purchases, which is what you were actually getting).  This of course assumes that `payDevTime` is actually stored in a sortable format (if it isn't you have bigger problems than this query not working quite right).

That said, there's a number of troubling things about your schema design.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, Clockwork-Muse. =) However, the time format wasn't problematic as varchar datatype. It worked smoothly with queries. For example, we were able to return students who eat between '11:30:00' and '12:00:00' on a particular day. We checked them on data and the result was true. So where may a problem exists about time, can you give an example?

Comment: `payDevTime` probably is in a sortable time format (eg, using `09:00:00` instead of `9:00:00`).  However, you'd be better served by combining the date and time columns, as the 'Date' type in Oracle has the time information in it (which is why I had to do the comparisons I did, as a range).